# Even empty Iphone App doesn't work on Phone

Tags: iphone

I am trying to run a new Iphone app, and altough it works fine on simulator, on actual device, it immediately exits.

Also when I run from SSh I get killed error.

I try to run an empty, blank, new project, again it exits immediately. The device is OS 3.0, and compiled in same version, also I have tried to compile for SDK 2.0 but no difference.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it signed with a valid certificate/profile and is that profile installed on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh, sorry, I've missed 'signing with ldid' step

Answer (score 1):

Check your mobileprovision files, and make sure they're up to date. Does the console print anything when it crashes in the debugger? Also, make sure your XIB files are correctly named, and, on the device, case IS important.

Comment: I am running on a jailbroken device, so no provisioning